# What happens when antimatter Interacts with itself?

Tags: particle-physics, antimatter

We know what happens when antimatter and matter collide, but what happens when antimatter interacts with itself?

Comment: What happens when matter interacts with itself? What is the C-image of that?

Comment: This question appears to be far too broad. Please be more specific about what you want to know.

Answer (score 6):

The only compound object that has been investigated is an antielectron in interaction with an antiproton. It was found to have the same spectrum as an ordinary hydrogen atom. (As was expected.)

PS: Very recent Nature article by Ahmadi et al gives an upper bound of $2.10^{-10}$: http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/vaap/ncurrent/pdf/nature21040.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Antimatter interacting with antimatter is thought to be just like matter interacting with matter. So if, for example, two positrons collide, they will bounce off of each other just like electrons do.